# How to stop iOS 13 Personal Hotspot dropping out after 3 minutes even when plugged into power?

Tags: ios, wifi, tethering

The Personal Hotspot on iOS 13 will stay on for long periods, when paired to Mac. (Note that the Mac -> iOS tethering has unique operating system support different to simply connecting to a wifi host.) This is when the iOS device is plugged into power.

In contrast, when shared over WIFI to a PC, it drops out after 3-7 minutes.  This is even when the iOS device hosting the internet connection is plugged into power. The same PC stays connected to an ADSL modem sharing over WIFI for hours. This occurs even though I leave the phone on the hotspot page in settings. I’m using the PC continuously (working from home) when this occurs.

My question is: **How to stop iOS 13 Personal Hotspot dropping out after 3 minutes even when plugged into power?**

Comment: This question is a bit disjointed... when you say "when shared over WiFi" do you mean that it worked fine with the IOS devices tethered (USB cable) but now it disconnects after about 5 minutes?  Then you rephrase the question but emphasize power - was it plugged in to power (charging) when connected to the Apple devices and not with the PC?  Please clarify as it's difficult to see what you're trying to describe.

Comment: leave the phone on the personal hotspot page in settings.

Comment: So it works when acting as a hotspot for a Mac, but it doesn't when acting as a hotspot for a PC, correct? Any settings on Windows side which might cause this?

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful. I’ve updated the question.

Comment: If you're allowing the PC to sleep, its wifi will go down, and the phone will stop beaconing shortly after the PC disconnects.  When the PC comes back up, the phone will not start again.  The "ADSL modem" you describe likely does not drop beaconing even with no clients connected to it.

Comment: That’s helpful. I’ve updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The hotspot on iOS 13 is stable and solid for me to connect windows 10 and iOS and macOS from 10.13 and higher for more than an hour, so the presumption that iOS is the culprit might be worth investigating.

At worst, your device needs an erase and install if its struggling to share out the network. Do you suspect your iOS device needs repair or are you in an enviromnemt where WiFi interference is high?